# Bug Eclipse IDE gets closed when GlassFish's admin console tab is closed

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-3

I've recently noticed a very weird behavior I've with my GlassFish (v3.1.2) on Eclipse Java EE (Juno). Whenever I open the admin console of my GlassFish instance inside Eclipse then close its tab, Eclipse is closed as well for no apparent reason.

I've spent lot of time to find a solution for this problem but couldn't find one.

Edit : i've jdk6 and jdk7 (both are 32 versions) and running a win 7 x64 OS. I also found a log file related to this error (the file gets created everytime eclipse gets closed due to this error) i've uploaded here :

[log file link](http://www.4shared.com/file/bXy9CJCE/hs_err_pid1436.html?refurl=d1url)

Comment: Report this to the GlassFish or GlassFish Tools folks.

Comment: Here's the Bug Issue : http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18979